# write the following in sigma notation $a^k+a^{2k} +a^{4k} +a^{8k} +a^{{16}k} ...+a^{{256}k}$

Tags: induction, number-systems

I see the pattern being $2k$ on the power, and I thought the formula would just be $a^{(2k)}$, but i feel like im missing something else here  ? Why is it not The summation from $a=1$ to $128 = a^{2k}$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your fourth term must be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you fix your fourth term:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^8 a^{2^n k}$$

Comment: Sir, what's the issue with the 4th term?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the upper bound for summation should be 8 right instead of $\infty$ ?

Comment: Your fourth term *USED* to be $8 a^k$ before @CottonHeaded... fixed it.

Comment: +1 Not mine btw OP's